# AKF Scale cube alternatives?

Tags: scalability

The AKF scale cube is a qualitative mean to measure the scalability of a system.
This model has been introduced in the book the "Art of scalability". You can find a succinct description [here](https://akfpartners.com/growth-blog/scale-cube).

I am wondering if there are alternatives to the scale cube, to assess **qualitatively** the scalability of a system.

(In case this question is off-topic, let me know if there are better suited places for this kind of questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to AKF, there is Transactional Auto Scaler (TAS), Scalability Patterns Language Map(SPLM) and Person Achieved Ubiquitous Manufacturing(PAUM)... 
This [pdf](http://home.ufam.edu.br/hiramaral/04_SIAPE_FINAL_2016/SIAPE_Biblioteca%20Geral/00000_MeDSE_Mendeley_2015/011_MAS/2013_PUTNIK_Scalability%20in%20manufact%20uring%20system%20Stateofart.pdf) describes the assessment models (Quantitative/Qualitative) of scalability, in different areas such as: Manufacturing Systems, Computer Science, Organizational and Business.

*Edit1*

If the above models do not measure or at least help measure -I think-, please consider this [researche](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322058399_Scalability_measurement_of_business_process_model_using_business_processes_similarity_and_complexity) 
 to measure the scalability which discusses several technics.

[Scalability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) can be measured in various dimensions, such as:

Administrative scalability: The ability for an increasing number of organizations or users to easily share a single distributed system.
Functional scalability: The ability to enhance the system by adding new functionality at minimal effort.

Geographic scalability: The ability to maintain performance, usefulness, or usability regardless of expansion from concentration in a local area to a more distributed geographic pattern.

Load scalability, And so on..

`AKF` looks like a model not an approach to measure scalability, from the definition:

"The Scale Cube helps teams keep critical dimensions of system scale `in mind` when solutions are designed and when existing systems `are being improved`. "

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I really appreciate your answer. However, I am not 100% sure that TAS, SPLM and PAUM can be considered alternatives to the AFK cube ( I mean from the qualitative assessment of scalability point of view, not as models). What do you think about that?

Comment: @Briomkez I though about it, and I am convenced they are models to help assess the scalability, I updated the unswer to add a research on how to measure it. I wanted to say that AKF itself is a model of assessment, what do you think about that?

Comment: Yeah you are right about the scale cube, it is a conceptual model rather than an evaluation framework. It was my misconception about the other models (due to the lack of familiarity with those models from my side). I thank you for the time taken and the throughout insight.